# mysql explode inside a query

Tags: php, mysql

Ok i'm a bit confused to whether what i want to do is possible or not.

in the database the fields 'slot' contain information in the form (first piece:second piece:third piece) where : is the delimiter.

I need to compare `$matchid` to the first piece of the field. so let's say `slot1 = 100:200:300`

i need to check whether `$matchid` equals to the first piece of any field in the database

```
$matchid = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query(
     "SELECT `matchid` 
      FROM `matches` 
      WHERE `winner` = 0 AND 
            (`slot1` OR `slot2` OR `slot3` OR `slot4` OR `slot5` 
             OR `slot6` OR `slot7` OR `slot8` OR `slot9` OR `slot10`) = $matchid"
      ));
```

If `$matchid` was 100 originally and `slot1 = 100:200:300` than the query won't return anything but i need this to be a match.

i don't know if i've explained this properly but here we go. I tried using explode but didn't really work

Comment: Why don't you put them in individual columns? Rather them in one column.

Comment: then i would have 30 columns instead of 10.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: are you saying i should rewrite all my queries? sounds very time consuming. Just because they are deprecated does that mean they won't work later?

Comment: Whats the problem of having 30 columns of normalized data?

Comment: its easier to keep track of 10 columns than 30.

Comment: Then why not use one column with 30 values seperated by ":"? Sorry, but that is just ridiculous...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work with your existing data structure, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT `matchid` FROM `matches` 
WHERE `winner` = 0 AND (
  `slot1` LIKE "{$matchid}:%" 
  OR `slot2` LIKE "{$matchid}:%"
  /* etc, etc... */
)
```

That being said, you'll have a much cleaner query if you separate slots into their own table.
Also, either escape $matchid or use a prepared statement.

Comment: The curly braces are escaped by php when you wrap the entire string in  double quotes... just replace the whole `{$matchid}` bit with the actual variable value, however you choose to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$matchid = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT `matchid` FROM `matches` WHERE `winner` = 0 AND         (`slot1` OR `slot2` OR `slot3` OR `slot4` OR `slot5` OR `slot6` OR `slot7` OR `slot8` OR `slot9` OR `slot10`) = ".$matchid));
```

notice the dot to concatenate the strings. In this way the php passes the real value of $matchid, whereas in your code you were passing the string "$matchid".

In the case $matchid is an integer you have to use strval($matchid) in the query.

Comment: this does not relate to my question